# How would you apply high voltage on a piece of dielectric making sure breakdown does not occur?

Tags: high-voltage, insulation, piezoelectricity, dielectric-breakdown

Say you have a piece of dielectric with a breakdown electric field, BDE. For some experimental requirement you have to apply an electric field, E > BDE, across the piece of dielectric without reaching breakdown. So you place the dielectric between 2 plates/electrodes with appropriate spacing to reach the desired field, E. Now, to prevent breakdown you insulate the electrodes with another dielectric that has a breakdown electric field, BDE2 >> E. Would this technique work to achieve my goal or is there something I am missing?

The above scenario is related to controlling the behavior of a ferroelectric.

Comment: But you are still applying an electric field > BDE across the original dielectric, right?

Comment: I don't get it. If you don't want breakdown, just keep the applied voltage below BDE. What you suggest is that somehow you will apply a field above BDE but there will not be breakdown??

Comment: @JohnD yes, the electrodes would be kept at E > BDE.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson What you think I suggested is what I actually suggested. My reasoning is, dielectric breakdown occurs when the leakage current through the material rises sharply to a non-negligible value. But if you insulate the electrodes with another dielectric with 'extraordinary' dielectric strength, you could prevent the current flow even though the electric field exceeds the breakdown of the 1st dielectric, which happens to be sitting between the 2 insulated electrodes. I am curious, if there is anything wrong with this technique?

Answer (score 2):

When an insulating dielectric is subjected to a high electric field, the electrons in the
valence band can overcome the energy gap and get excited to the conduction band. The mobile electrons are accelerated by electric field and so by collisions they excite more electrons to the conduction band resulting in an avalanche of conduction electrons.

This will happen in the presence of your electric field even if your electrodes are perfectly insulated with another material.  All it requires is the electric field strength at the dielectric to be greater than the breakdown value.

It's the field itself causing the breakdown, not conduction from the electrodes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an E>BDE in the dielectric or not?

You can get away by momentarily spiking E>BDE and bringing it back down quickly i.e. pulse it for a short duration.

Comment: I want to reach a certain E, but unfortunately this happens to satisfy E>BDE.

I require a constant electric field, so pulses wont work for this. But you had a good idea.